# React Native OnPress issue i have been having

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and have been doing this for a week or so. I just finished the tutorials for making an interactive buttons and work on it. But i am stuck on this. The app is really simple right now, just trying to make a form and add some trigger event using ***onPress*** on it.

Below is the portion of my code. I am simply lost for words why its not calling ***SubmitThisForm()*** on the onPress event.

Can you guys help me on this.

Thanks a lot.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Container, Content, InputGroup,Button, View, Icon, Card, 
CardItem, Text, Body} from 'native-base';

import {Input} from './common';

 class LoginForm extends Component {
 state = {email: '', password: ''};
 SubmitThisForm() {
  console.log("Can you see this");
 }
render () {
 return (
  <Container>
    <Content>
      <Card style={styles.FormContainer}>
        <CardItem>
          <Body>
            <InputGroup borderType="regular">
              <Icon name="ios-mail-outline" style={{color:'#384850'}}/>
              <Input
                placeHolder="example@example.com"
                value = {this.state.email}
                onChangeText={email=>this.setState( { email })}
              />
            </InputGroup>

            <InputGroup borderType="regular">

              <Icon name="lock" style={{color:'#384850'}}/>
              <Input
                secureTextEntry= {true}
                placeHolder="password"
                value = {this.state.password}
                onChangeText={password=>this.setState( { password })}
              />
            </InputGroup>

          </Body>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
      <View style={styles.SignIn}>
        <Button block warning onPress={ () => {this.SubmitThisForm()}}><Text>Sign In</Text></Button>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.SignUp}>
        <Button block info><Text>Sign Up</Text></Button>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.SignIn}>
        <Button block primary><Text>Forgot Password</Text></Button>
      </View>
    </Content>

  </Container>
  );
  };
  }

  const styles = {
  ErrorTextStyle: {
fontSize: 20,
alignSelf: 'center',
color: 'red'
},
FormContainer:{
marginTop:30,
shadowColor:'#000',
shadowOffset:{width:0,height:2},
shadowOpacity:0.1,
shadowRadius:2,
},
SignIn:{

marginTop:10,
flex:1,
alignSelf:'stretch',
},
SignUp:{

marginTop:40,
flex:1,
alignSelf:'stretch',
}
}

export default LoginForm
```

The include input component is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, TextInput} from 'react-native';

const Input = ({ label,value,onChangeText,placeHolder,secureTextEntry }) => {

 const {InputStyle,LabelStyle,ContainerStyle } = styles;
 return (
 <View style = {ContainerStyle}>
  <TextInput
    secureTextEntry = {secureTextEntry}
    placeholder={placeHolder}
    autoCorrect={false}
    style = {InputStyle}
    value={value}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
  />
</View>
  );
 };

 const styles = {
 InputStyle:{
color:'#000',
paddingRight:5,
paddingLeft:5,
fontSize:18,
lineHeight:30,
flex:2,
height:40
},
LabelStyle:{
fontSize:18,
paddingLeft:20,
flex:1,
},
ContainerStyle:{
height:40,
flex:1,
flexDirection:'row',
alignItems:'center'
}
}

 export { Input };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use an Arrow function, or `bind()` `SubmitThisForm` to your Component.

1. You can either declare your method like:

   `SubmitThisForm = () => {
      console.log('Can you see this?')
   }`
2. Or, you can `bind()` your function in the `constructor` by adding:

   `constructor() {
     super()
     this.SubmitThisForm = this.SubmitThisForm.bind(this)
   }`

If you do not bind `this` in  your custom functions, `this` will equal `undefined`. When you use Arrow functions however, `this` is lexically scoped which means the context of `this` will be the enclosing context (`LoginForm`)